# How to create a specific chart in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, rank

Below is the sample data and a few manipulations. The chart that I am attempting to create is one where the cnty1 would be listed left to right in ascending order. The vertical axis would be for the number of times that something appears in the top 5 employers. Each row is an employer, I just keep the names off for confidentiality. The chart would not be a bar or line chart but rather one where the industry's would be represented by different color dots.

For example, Cnty = '003' would have four dots (for industry 514,615,312,and 722) and a data label of 1 for each dot because each 3 digit industry code (Naics) only appears once in the top 5 list for each quarter.

It would not be a scatter plot because if industry 721 appeared 3 times and had cnty = 003 attached to it.. the dot would get bigger.

Edit: This would be a bubble-chart as found on https://r-graph-gallery.com/bubble-chart.html. The size variable would be how many times it is shows up for a given cnty1.

So I guess my main question is how to create a column that shows many times an industry shows up in the top 5 for a given cnty1.

```
 year1 <- c(2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020,2020)
 qtr1 <- c(01,01,01,01,01,01,01,01,02,02,02,02,02,02,02,02)
 cnty1 <- c(003,003,001,003,031,031,003,005,001,003,003,007,031,001,003,017)
 employment1 <- c(140,251,25,36,99,8415,2514,33141,20,14,185,220,336,901,12,5)
 industry1 <- c(312,312,721,721,912,312,514,541,651,721,722,722,612,613,615,312)


 dfemp <- data.frame(year1,qtr1,cnty1,employment1,industry1)

 dfemp$date<- ymd(paste(dfemp$year1,dfemp$qtr1,"1",sep="-"))

 dfemp <- dfemp %>% arrange(desc(date)) %>% group_by(date)%>%slice_max(order_by = employment1,n=5)
```

Comment: https://r-graph-gallery.com/ is a good reference for finding different plots and ways to make them.

Comment: @r2evans, Thanks. I knew that I had seen this construct before just could not think of a name.

Comment: It seems like row 15 (cnty1 3 and industry1 615) is the 7th largest employment1 for that quarter, wouldn't it be excluded?

Comment: It might help to add a picture. Are the dots' heights lined up with their industry, or stacked, or bunched in a vertical arrangement? Is the number of occasions in the top 5 controlling the bubble size, it's vertical placement, or both?

Comment: @JonSpring. Your answer below works. Only a few tweaks that I want to see if it can be done. First, is there a way to have a unique color of dot for each column or cnty1? Second, is the scale_size_area where you would have the dot get bigger as the number of occurrences grows.

Comment: You could add `color = as.factor(cnty1)` into the `aes()` to color based on `cnty1`. The `scale_size_area` is added here to make the size vary so the the area is 2x for values that are 2x, instead of the default of making the radius 2x (so the area is 4x). Aesthetic choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dfemp %>%
  group_by(year1, qtr1) %>%
  slice_max(employment1, n = 5) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  count(cnty1, industry1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.factor(cnty1), as.factor(industry1), size = n, label = n)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(color = "white", size = 4) +
  scale_size_area() +
  guides(size = "none")
```

[image]